# Can this be done with sed?

Tags: sed, python

I wrote a simple python program to do some text processing. I wanted to split sentences into lines with sed, using the text from a screenplay/stage play as input. I tried to write it in sed, but could not. I am wondering if it can be done with sed?

```py
    import re
    
    test_txt = """
    Brigitte:
    Ich hoffe, du hast während des Lockdowns nicht alle Benimmregeln vergessen.
    Bernd:
    Entschuldige bitte. Das muss an der Vorfreude liegen. Endlich wieder kann ich meinen
    Cappuccino im Sitzen genießen und muss ihn nicht heimlich aus einem Pappbecher in
    irgendeiner Nische in der Fußgängerzone trinken. Wie nervig das war, Maske runter,
    einen Schluck trinken, Maske wieder auf, und immer die Gegend im Blick haben, damit ich
    die Leute vom Ordnungsamt rechtzeitig sehe.
    Brigitte:
    Das ist mal wieder typisch. Du denkst nur an dich und lässt dabei das Wesentliche aus
    den Augen.
    Bernd:
    Häh?
    (Fesnik erscheint, bringt die Karten)
    Fesnik:
    Herzlich willkommen im Adria, schön, dass sie bei uns sind.
    Bernd:
    Ich habe Ihren Cappuccino wirklich vermisst.
    Brigitte:
    Wir hatten schon Angst, dass Sie nicht wieder aufmachen.
    Fesnik:
    Eine unbegründete Sorge, Signorina.
    (Fesnik ab, Bernd und Brigitte studieren die Karten)
    Brigitte:
    Signorina heißt Fräulein, wusstest du das eigentlich? Typisch Italiener, schleimen uns
    """
    
        actor_pattern = '.+:'
        lines = test_txt.splitlines()
        speech = ''
        i = 0
        while i < len(lines):
            if re.match(actor_pattern, lines[i]):
                while True:
                    speech += lines[i].replace('\n', ' ').replace(
                        '. ', '.\n').replace(
                        '? ', '?\n').replace(
                        '! ', '!\n').replace(
                        ') ', ')\n')
                    i += 1
                    if not i < len(lines):
                        break
                    if re.match(actor_pattern, lines[i]):
                        print('')
                        break
            else:
                i += 1
            print(speech, end='')
            speech = ''
        print('\nEND')
```

The output is thus:

```
Brigitte:Ich hoffe, du hast während des Lockdowns nicht alle Benimmregeln vergessen.
Bernd:Entschuldige bitte.
Das muss an der Vorfreude liegen.
Endlich wieder kann ich meinenCappuccino im Sitzen genießen und muss ihn nicht heimlich aus einem Pappbecher inirgendeiner Nische in der Fußgängerzone trinken.
Wie nervig das war, Maske runter,einen Schluck trinken, Maske wieder auf, und immer die Gegend im Blick haben, damit ichdie Leute vom Ordnungsamt rechtzeitig sehe.
Brigitte:Das ist mal wieder typisch.
Du denkst nur an dich und lässt dabei das Wesentliche ausden Augen.
Bernd:Häh?(Fesnik erscheint, bringt die Karten)
Fesnik:Herzlich willkommen im Adria, schön, dass sie bei uns sind.
Bernd:Ich habe Ihren Cappuccino wirklich vermisst.
Brigitte:Wir hatten schon Angst, dass Sie nicht wieder aufmachen.
Fesnik:Eine unbegründete Sorge, Signorina.(Fesnik ab, Bernd und Brigitte studieren die Karten)
Brigitte:Signorina heißt Fräulein, wusstest du das eigentlich?
Typisch Italiener, schleimen uns
END
```

The code finds an actor_pattern, joins to the next line, then breaks each sentence onto a new line until it finds another actor_pattern, then continues in this way through the lines.

Comment: In the future, please take a look at the community guidelines for writing a good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Importantly, please provide a descriptive title, explain the problem you're trying to solve, and (when possible) include a minimum working example.

In this case, I'm inferring that you want to split sentences into lines with sed, using the text from a screenplay/stage play as input. If that's a correct interpretation, please add that info to the question.

Comment: #rexypoo: thank you for the guidance. It is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your "actor_pattern" and its usage are. How far would this simple `sed` get you? It's quite close to your desired result, but may need some refinement:

```
sed -Ez 's/\n/ /g; s/([.?!)]) ([^(])/\1\n\2/g' file
Brigitte: Ich hoffe, du hast während des Lockdowns nicht alle Benimmregeln vergessen.
Bernd: Entschuldige bitte.
Das muss an der Vorfreude liegen.
Endlich wieder kann ich meinen Cappuccino im Sitzen genießen und muss ihn nicht heimlich aus einem Pappbecher in irgendeiner Nische in der Fußgängerzone trinken.
Wie nervig das war, Maske runter, einen Schluck trinken, Maske wieder auf, und immer die Gegend im Blick haben, damit ich die Leute vom Ordnungsamt rechtzeitig sehe.
Brigitte: Das ist mal wieder typisch.
Du denkst nur an dich und lässt dabei das Wesentliche aus den Augen.
Bernd: Häh? (Fesnik erscheint, bringt die Karten)
Fesnik: Herzlich willkommen im Adria, schön, dass sie bei uns sind.
Bernd: Ich habe Ihren Cappuccino wirklich vermisst.
Brigitte: Wir hatten schon Angst, dass Sie nicht wieder aufmachen.
Fesnik: Eine unbegründete Sorge, Signorina. (Fesnik ab, Bernd und Brigitte studieren die Karten)
Brigitte: Signorina heißt Fräulein, wusstest du das eigentlich?
Typisch Italiener, schleimen uns
```

`sed` version is (GNU sed) 4.7.
The script is using the `-z` option (not available on all versions) to read the entire text into memory, then replaces all `<NL>` character by a space, thus forming one long line, then adds `<NL>` chars after all sentence ending characters.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. That works great! I did not think to do it that way, but it works.